# pandas filtering and comparing dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sql file which consists of the data below which I read into pandas.

```
df = pandas.read_sql('Database count details', con=engine,
                     index_col='id', parse_dates='newest_available_date')
```

**Output**

```
id       code   newest_date_available
9793708  3514   2015-12-24
9792282  2399   2015-12-25
9797602  7452   2015-12-25
9804367  9736   2016-01-20
9804438  9870   2016-01-20
```

The next line of code is to get last week's date

```
date_before = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7) # Which is 2016-01-20
```

What I am trying to do is, to compare `date_before` with `df` and print out all rows that is less than `date_before`

```
if (df['newest_available_date'] < date_before):
    print(#all rows)
```

Obviously this returns me an error

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Also ensure that your column is datetime type. Use df.dtypes

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would do a mask like:

```
a = df[df['newest_date_available'] < date_before]
```

If `date_before = datetime.date(2016, 1, 19)`, this returns:

```
        id  code newest_date_available
0  9793708  3514            2015-12-24
1  9792282  2399            2015-12-25
2  9797602  7452            2015-12-25
```

Comment: I still get the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: I copied your dataframe and read it back with `df = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=['newest_date_available'])`, and for then the process worked fine. Try to do it in this way and let me know if you still have issues. Remember that the `parse_dates` parameter requires a list so in your `pd.read_sql(parse_dates=['newest_available_data'])`.

Comment: I copied `a = df[df['newest_date_available'] < date_before]` with `print(a)` and it worked! But I got the error when I was trying to fit it into the `if` statement because I wanted to do something like `if a is true: merge id with code` something like that.

Comment: Consider posting a new question about that, your original question was only about filtering and printing out dates according to some rules. Thanks.

Comment: why `<` and `<=` works same ? what if i want excluding mentioned date?

Answer (score 29):

Using `datetime.date(2019, 1, 10)` works because pandas coerces the date to a date time under the hood.

This however, will no longer be the case in future versions of pandas.

From version 0.24 and up, it now issues a warning:

> FutureWarning: Comparing Series of datetimes with 'datetime.date'.
> Currently, the 'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future
> pandas will not coerce, and a TypeError will be raised.

The better solution is the one proposed on [its official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) as Pandas' replacement for Python's `datetime.datetime` object.

To provide an example referencing OP's initial dataset, this is how you would use it:

```
import pandas
cond1 = df.newest_date_available < pd.Timestamp(2016,1,10)
df.loc[cond1, ]
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party but I think it is worth mentioning. If you are looking for a solution which dynamically considers the date a week ago, this might be helpful:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'alpha': list('ABCDE'), 'num': range(5), 'date': pd.date_range('2022-06-30', '2022-07-04')})

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
  alpha  num       date
0     A    0 2022-06-30
1     B    1 2022-07-01
2     C    2 2022-07-02
3     D    3 2022-07-03
4     E    4 2022-07-04

In [5]: df.query('date < "%s"' % (pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - pd.Timedelta(7, 'd')))
Out[5]: 
  alpha  num       date
0     A    0 2022-06-30
1     B    1 2022-07-01
```

---

**Explanation:**
I created a new `df` with newer dates. Today is *2022-07-09* (`pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()`) and seven days ago it was *2022-07-02* (`pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - pd.Timedelta(7, 'd')`). [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) returns only those observations where the dates in column `date` are smaller than *2022-07-02* using the string formatting operator [`%`](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-string-formatting/).
`normalize()` is important here to reset the time to midnight. Otherwise `query()` will also return observations equal to *2022-07-02*, because:

```
# Timestamp('2022-07-09 17:53:03.078172') > Timestamp('2022-07-09 00:00:00')
In [6]: pd.Timestamp.now() > pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()
Out[6]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error while filtering for date:

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date
```

When trying this answer:

```
date_before = datetime.date(2016, 1, 19)
df[df['newest_date_available'] < date_before]
```

...it may be that your date column contains the other popular date type in pandas. Fix it like this:

```
import numpy as np

date_before = np.datetime64(datetime.date(2016, 1, 19))
df[df['newest_date_available'] < date_before]
```