# Boolean mask from pandas datetime index using .loc accessor

Tags: python, performance, pandas, datetime

Asumme the following toy code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
avec = np.random.rand(len(rng))
bvec = np.random.rand(len(rng))
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":avec,"B":bvec}, index=rng)
```

I can now select a part of the time interval with

```
df.loc["2011-01-02",:]
```

Is there a way to efficiently access the boolean mask that corresponds to the resulting slice, i.e:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

I have tried the suggestions in [an earlier stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162585/filtering-and-comparing-dates-with-pandas) but `df.index.date` takes a very long time to run on my dataset...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If performance is important chain 2 boolean masks:

```
(df.index >= "2011-01-02") & (df.index < "2011-01-03")
```

Comment: I'm curious on why you say "if performance is important"? Do you think the syntax is unclear and could be better if performance wasn't important?

Comment: @roganjosh - I think compare solution with `isin`, but I have to test it  for 100% sure :)

Comment: It is indeed faster, I just timed it.

Comment: Ah, I prefer your solution as it is! :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this:

```
df.index.isin(df.loc["2011-01-02",:].index)

array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

However, @jezrael's answer is faster. I leave this up as an alternative solution. The only convenience that this provides is if you want to refer to your sliced dataframe by name, rather than by the date string, for instance:

```
# named slice of your original dataframe:
sliced_df = df.loc["2011-01-02",:]
# get boolean array:
df.index.isin(sliced_df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `numpy` representation of your index and compare with a `np.datetime64` object:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

(df.index.values >= np.datetime64(datetime.strptime("2011-01-02", '%Y-%m-%d'))) & \
(df.index.values < np.datetime64(datetime.strptime("2011-01-03", '%Y-%m-%d')))
```

**Note on behaviour**

The solution above is specific to the query in the question. As @Jeff points out, string representations of `datetime` use partial indexing. So using `numpy` should only be used in specific cases.

See `pandas` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#indexing) on `datetime` indexing for more details.

**Performance benchmarking**

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%timeit (df.index >= "2011-01-02") & (df.index < "2011-01-03")

%timeit (df.index.values >= np.datetime64(datetime.strptime("2011-01-02", '%Y-%m-%d'))) & \
        (df.index.values < np.datetime64(datetime.strptime("2011-01-03", '%Y-%m-%d')))

assert ((df.index >= "2011-01-02") & (df.index < "2011-01-03") == \
        (df.index.values >= np.datetime64(datetime.strptime("2011-01-02", '%Y-%m-%d'))) & \
        (df.index.values < np.datetime64(datetime.strptime("2011-01-03", '%Y-%m-%d')))).all()

# 1.21 ms ± 23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 527 µs ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: these are not the same generally ; string datetimes use partial indexing. offering up a numpy soln is often a special case and not recommended

Comment: docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#indexing

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It's definitely faster than jezreal's but the difference decrease a little bit on large datasets and I'm a bit worried about memory consumption. I wish there was a way to get the equivalent to df.index == "2011-01-02" with partial indexing...