# Filter a DataFrame By Date One Week Previous From Current Date

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an .xlsx spreadsheet into a Pandas DataFrame so that I can remove duplicate rows based on all columns and export the DataFrame into a .csv. One of the columns is a date column formatted as MM/DD/YY.

[Here is a sample of the unaltered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl0VE.png)

This spreadsheet contains abnormal pay hours entries for a payroll that is payed every Friday based on hours from one week previous to the current week. Rows are added each day there is an abnormal function with that day's data. I want to tell pandas to only find duplicates in rows whose date is less than or equal to the Friday date one week previous from the current Friday (This script will only be ran on Fridays). For example, if today is Friday 12/7/18, I want to set a cutoff date of the previous Friday, 11/30/18, and only look at rows whose dates are on or before 11/30/18. How can I trim the DataFrame in this way before executing drop_duplicates?

Comment: Please share some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104500/pandas-filtering-and-comparing-dates

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use date and timedelta.

get todays date.
store the date one week from todays date.
filter your data (I'm not sure how you have it stored, but I used generic names)

```
from datetime import date, timedelta   


today = date.today()
week_prior =  today - timedelta(weeks=1)

df_last_week = df[df['date'] <= week_prior]
```

Comment: It works for me only if I use df_last_week = df[df['date'].dt.datetime <= week_prior] typing the dataframe column as a datetime

Comment: ah yes. My solution is under the assumption that column is datetime object.

Comment: Same answer with pandas functions `pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.Timedelta(weeks=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Note that using a fixed time window of 1 week (or 7 days) is fine if you are **sure** that your script will **only ever** be run on a Friday.

You can, of course programatically get the date of last Friday, and filter your dataframe on that date:

```
last_friday = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=datetime.now().weekday()) + timedelta(days=4, weeks=-1)
print(df[df['date'] <= pd.Timestamp(last_friday)])
```