# Find the newest row per column

Tags: python, pandas

I have pretty large (about 2 million rows) csv table from this kind:

```
|  id  |     status         |      date           |
|------|--------------------|---------------------|
|  55  |    'blah blah'     |  29-02-12 21:00:00  |
|  55  |    'yoyoyoyoyo'    |  29-02-12 22:00:00  |
|  44  |    'qwertyuiop'    |  29-02-12 21:30:00  |
```

My wanted output is getting the newest row per each id and the amount of rows per id:

```
|  id  |     status         |      last_date      |  amount |
|------|--------------------|---------------------|---------|
|  55  |    'yoyoyoyoyo'    |  29-02-12 22:00:00  |    2    |
|  44  |    'qwertyuiop'    |  29-02-12 21:30:00  |    1    |
```

And save the wanted output to another csv file.

I pretty new to pandas, is it something should/can be done with pandas? If yes, can you please give a hint to relevant functions?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104500/pandas-filtering-and-comparing-dates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First if necessary convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then get indices by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and select by `loc`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('id', sort=False)['date'].idxmax()]
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['id','date'], ascending=[True, False]).drop_duplicates('id')
```

Last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) by original column:

```
df1['amount'] = df1['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts())
print (df1)
   id        status                date  amount
1  55  'yoyoyoyoyo' 2012-02-29 22:00:00       2
2  44  'qwertyuiop' 2012-02-29 21:30:00       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use `.transform` twice with `.max` and `.size` like the following:

```
# Convert our date columns to datetime format
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# Create the amount and last_date column with transform 
df['amount']= df.groupby('id').id.transform('size')
df['last_date'] = df.groupby('id').date.transform('max')

print(df)
   id      status                date  amount           last_date
0  55   blah blah 2012-02-29 21:00:00       2 2012-02-29 22:00:00
1  55  yoyoyoyoyo 2012-02-29 22:00:00       2 2012-02-29 22:00:00
2  44  qwertyuiop 2012-02-29 21:30:00       1 2012-02-29 21:30:00

# Filter the rows we need and drop date column we dont need anymore
df = df[df.date == df.last_date].drop('date', axis=1)

print(df)
   id      status  amount           last_date
1  55  yoyoyoyoyo       2 2012-02-29 22:00:00
2  44  qwertyuiop       1 2012-02-29 21:30:00
```