# Input function to search for starting and end date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, input

I want to ask the user of the program to input the starting and end date (so pandas filters only the necessary dates). But unfortunately it doesn't work out with the input feature. When I just input the date into start like this: '01-01-2000' it works. The same for the end: '31-12-2009'.

```
start = year,month,day = input().split('-')
end = year,month,day = input().split('-')


df= pd.read_excel('path', skiprows = 6, converters = {'Date':str})
df= df[(df['Date'] >= start)]
df= df[(df['Date'] <= end)]
df
```

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104500/pandas-filtering-and-comparing-dates) answers your question already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas filtering and comparing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104500/pandas-filtering-and-comparing-dates)

Comment: I am sorry but no. For me it isn't clear how to link it with the input function - thank your for your help.

Comment: The main issue is, that in the first step a list is generated but actually I just need the date like in the example in the description.

Comment: Do, you mean , you want to convert the input to a [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) format?

Comment: Exactly, that would be the goal. So whenever a new Excel is imported and someone needs to change the starting and end date, he can only type in 2000-01-01 f.e.

Because I am using the following type, to filter inside the pd import:

df= df[(df['Date'] >= start)]
df= df[(df['Date'] <= end)]

Comment: Then you can convert the user input to datetime format using `pd.to_datetime`, and the columns in the excel can also be converted in the case they aren't in that.

Comment: If you look at my code at the top, I am asking the user of the Pythom programm to type in what is the desired starting date and what is the desired end date of the filter (That is happening with the input() function) and there he is supposed to type in 2000-01-01. Based on that input, the start date f.e. has to be 2000-01-01(connected with that also the filtering has to start from that date on, the excel file was already importated at that point) but because it is a str it should be '2000-01-01'. ATM it creates a list what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
start = year,month,day = input().split('-')
start = datetime(year = int(year), month = int(month), day = int(day))

end = year, month, day = input().split('-')
end = datetime(year = int(year), month = int(month), day = int(day))

df = pd.read_excel('path', skiprows = 6)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d", errors = "coerce", origin = "1900-01-01")

df = df[(df['Date'] >= start) & (df['Date'] <= end)]
df
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution to my question. The only part that generated and error was the 'origin = ' part. As soon as I cut that out, it worked perfectly for me - thank you.