# How to get the rows which in between some date

Tags: pandas

i have excel sheet which is below

```
id date
1 Friday, June 26, 2020
2 Sunday, June 26, 2018
3 Sunday, June 26, 2019
```

- How to find the date between greater than 01/12/2020 and today's date

First i need to convert `Sunday, June 26, 2019` to `Sunday, June 26, 2019` to 26/06/2019

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel(r"test.xlsx",sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
    new_data = (df['date'] > '01/12/2020') & (df['date'] <= date.today())
```

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104500/pandas-filtering-and-comparing-dates). You need to use datetimes and not strings when comparing date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert values to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use similar like your solution with `today` with [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) for remove times from datetimes (set times to `00:00:00`):

```
print (df)
   id                      date
0   1  Friday, January 26, 2021 <- added datetimes for matching
1   2     Sunday, June 26, 2018
2   3     Sunday, June 26, 2019

df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%A, %B %d, %Y')

today = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d')
df1 = df[(df['date']> '2020-12-01') & (df['date']<= today)]

print (df1)
   id       date
0   1 2021-01-26
```

Comment: @Nons - Then try remove `df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%A, %B %d, %Y')` or `df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: I got True and False, How to print the dataframe

Comment: @Nons - I think `True, False`s are from `(df['date']> '2020-12-01') & (df['date']<= today)`, for filtering need `df[]` like `df[(df['date']> '2020-12-01') & (df['date']<= today)]`