# Filter records based on timestamp in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

| id | location | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 2022-01-01 17:00:00 |
| 001 | B | 2022-01-01 18:00:00 |
| 001 | B | 2022-01-01 18:15:00 |
| 002 | B | 2022-01-01 18:30:00 |
| 003 | B | 2022-01-01 19:00:00 |
| 003 | A | 2022-01-01 20:00:00 |

I'd like to filter records where location is B and only after the same id has visited location A (i.e. the timestamp of B is later than the timestamp of A). Desired output as below:

| id | location | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | B | 2022-01-01 18:00:00 |
| 001 | B | 2022-01-01 18:15:00 |

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with help of [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html):

```
# identify all times of a visit to A and after
m1 = df.sort_values('timestamp')['location'].eq('A').groupby(df['id']).cummax()
# identify location B
m2 = df['location'].eq('B')

# keep rows where both conditions above are True
df[m1&m2]
```

output:

```
   id location            timestamp
1   1        B  2022-01-01 18:00:00
2   1        B  2022-01-01 18:15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the dates via python comparators as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104500/pandas-filtering-and-comparing-dates):

```
filtered_records = records[records["timestamp"] > compared_record["timestamp"]]
```

The Location can be filteres in the same way:

```
filtered_records = records[records["location"] == compared_record["location"]]
```

So your final code would be:

```
filtered_records = records[(records["timestamp"] > compared_record["timestamp"]) && (records["location"] == compared_record["location"])]
```

Comment: May I know what's compared_record?

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    ss1=dd.sort_values(["timestamp","location"])[::-1].location.eq("B").cumprod()
    if ss1.loc[lambda x:x==0].size>0:
        return dd.loc[ss1.loc[lambda x:x==1].index]

df1.groupby('id').apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out：

```
  id location            timestamp
0   1        B  2022-01-01 18:15:00
1   1        B  2022-01-01 18:00:00
```